# Border on page's edge

Tags: margins, color

How can I make a black border close to pages edge ?

Answer (score 10):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor,lipsum,calc}

\newlength\myborder
\myborder=10pt%please adjust the border width :-)


\pagecolor{red}%please change it back to black :-)

\AddToShipoutPictureBG
{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft
    {%
        \color{white}%
    \hspace{\myborder}%
    \rule[\myborder]{\paperwidth-2\myborder}{\paperheight-2\myborder}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use TikZ in the following form:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{bordercolor}{cmyk}{1,.60,0,.40}

\begin{document}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] {%
\draw [bordercolor,line width=3mm]
(current page.south west)
rectangle
(current page.north east)
;}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

TikZ allows us to access all edges and the center of the current page with special node `currentpage`.